# Script fails to link "Random Value" node sockets in Geometry Nodes

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to create a python script which would automatically create and link certain nodes. However, despite my best efforts, the script fails to do so, which can be seen when comparing my code and the result:

```
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='NODES')
dowolny = bpy.context.active_object
node_group = bpy.context.object.modifiers[0].node_group

inputs = node_group.inputs
inputs.new(type = "NodeSocketInt", name = "Min in group")
inputs.new(type = "NodeSocketInt", name = "Max in group")
inputs.new(type = "NodeSocketObject", name = "Contents")
inputs.remove(inputs[0])

nodes       = node_group.nodes
randomval    = nodes.new(type="FunctionNodeRandomValue")
randomval.location.x -= 100
randomval.location.y -= 200
links = node_group.links
links.new(nodes["Group Input"].outputs["Min in group"],    randomval.inputs["Min"])
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Random Value has a lot of "Min" inputs: one for float, one for boolean, one for int:

[image]

Then you select float type, only one of them is visible, others are hidden. So the node is connected, but to the socket that's not visible. You should define socket by its index.

Comment: but what would be the index in my case?

Comment: I don't know, connect manually and check what index is connected